# How to extract cells that starts with specified string

Tags: python, openpyxl

Why is that return an error "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable"?
How can I extract cells that start with '1_'?

Thanks!

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('sample.xlsx')
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('strings')

for cell in list(sheet.columns)[3]:
    value = cell.value
    if value.startswith('1_'):
        print(value)
```

Comment: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable This means that you failed to load your file, basically None is meant as a placeholder till data comes, If you try to loop over it before storing datai it, you get that error.

Comment: Put `print (wb.sheetnames)` After loading your workbook, that will help you find out if your sheet is loaded or not.

Comment: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable so if we got this message that one of the method to solve is like to use 'if value'. Then that is going to filter None Type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is likely not an error in loading your file! Although you could use a print statement to double check that. With modules like openpyxl and xlwings, if there is no data explicitly stated in a cell the module returns a value of `None` so you are likely trying to perform a string operation on a `None` value. You can try to remedy this as such:

```
for cell in list(sheet.columns)[3]:
    value = cell.value
    if value: # ensure you are not reading an empty cell
        if value.startswith('1_'):
            print(value)
```

However, without a full stack trace all we can do is speculate about why you are receiving an error

Comment: Great! Your code is worked. I had to use filter with 'if value' so that can seek values except None Type.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the official documentation is a always a good place to start.

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('sample.xlsx')
sheet = wb['strings']

for cell in sheet['D']:
    value = cell.value
    if cell.value and value.startswith('1_'):
        print(value)
```